# How do the opacity values work?

Tags: css, opacity

I want to set the opacity of the draggable in my drag and drop game, but I dont really know what the numbers mean...

Can someone explain how I would make it really noticable when hovered over?

```
$('.drag').hover(

function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: "0.8"
});
}, 
function() {
$(this).stop().animate({
    opacity: "1"
});
});
```

Comment: it works between 0%-100%, which is the same as between 0 and 1. 0.53 = 53%.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it 0 = 0%, 1 = 100%.

So for instance, if you want something to be 50% transparent set the number to `0.5`, if you'd like something completely transparent choose `0`. Something with a value of `0.9` will be only very slightly transparent.

This forks for rgba too, for instance:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
```

...will produce a grey colour, as we're starting with black and making it 50% transparent (depending on the background of course).

> Can someone explain how I would make it really noticable when hovered over?

Set the hover value to something really low, for instance `0.4`, that'll be obvious, you may decide to continue tweaking the opacity until the hover and normal state compliment each other well.